# Motives and topological data analysis

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, motives

Here is some meta mathematics question.

During the last decade there has been some progress in the field of applied maths, called *topological data analysis*.

The setup starts with some set of points in some $n$ dimensional space.
Then tools (inspired) from topology like simplexes, rips and the so called persistence homology are applied.

Recently more and more attemps have been made to "enrich" this whole theory with a category theoretic fundament.

This paper by Bubenick and Milicevic is at the forefront of this developement:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05744

The classic idea of motives by Grothendieck is to introduce a motivic category $\mathcal{M}$, such that "every" cohomology functor $h: \mathcal{Schemes} \rightarrow Modules$ factors through $\mathcal{M}$. This is a very simplified explanation.

**Question:** Does any one know if there has been any research on connecting these fields?

In my opinion the question arises naturally. We have (co)-homology theory, so motives are the next step to abstraction.

My attempt would be to view a given set of points as the $k$-rational points of a variety over some field $k$. If one could compute a motive, then comparing two such sets on a very high level of abstration could be possible by comparing the motivic decompositions.

The usual problems are of course the lack of mixed motives and to prove good properties like Krull-Schmit for $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: The clearest analogue of motives in algebraic topology is not specific to TDA: spectra play a role for (pointed) topological spaces which is very much like the role motives play for smooth varieties. Just as the motive of a variety "records" precisely the data that Weil cohomology theories can detect about that variety, the suspension spectrum of a (pointed) topological space "records" precisely the data that generalized homology theories can detect about that space. If you want something more TDA-specific, something for point clouds, perhaps filtered suspension spectra are what you want.

Comment: I personally think that working with motives is a little out of reach at the moment. I think arguably the three most important instances of cohomology theories (conjecturally) unified by motives are Betti, de Rham and etale cohomologies. But I think the first two are kind of indistinguishable on simplicial complexes, where TDA happens. The last one becomes probably even weirder, because I'm not sure if there's a meaningful notion of schemes in computational / approximate settings.

Comment: In the same spirit, the effectiveness of motives in algebraic geometry is rooted in the fact that the cohomology (or: cohomologies) of algebraic varieties carry a lot of extra structure (Hodge structure, Galois action), which (mostly conjecturally) is closely related to algebraic cycles. In contrast, it seems that the use of cohomology in TDA goes in the opposite way: we are content even with a rough estimate of the rank of some cohomology group, and it is unclear what extra structure we could have on it. At least that is my naive understanding of the situation in TDA.

Answer (score 4):

For whatever it is worth, here is a link to a paper that you may find interesting. [Nori diagrams and persistent homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10301#:%7E:text=Recently%2C%20it%20was%20found%20that,pure%20mathematics%2C%20on%20the%20other.) (arXiv:1901.10301) by Yuri Manin and Matilde Marcolli

Comment: Great suggestion. I had no idea Manin is researching Nori motives too.